# python: problems with greater than

Tags: python, coordinates

So I have a problem.
I write a programm to figure out how many triangles are in a given set of lines and I want to calculate that with the line intersections.

I have a problem with line intersections. My problems are to figure out if the intersection is in the line segments. Here is my code:

```
def Schnittkorrekt (xs,ys,x1,x2,y1,y2):
    global y
    global x
    global z
    global w
    global c
    global x3
    global y3
    global z2
    global w2
    global x21
    global x22
    global y21
    global y22
    print (Schnittpunkt(x1,x2,y1,y2,x21,x22,y21,y22))
    if (x1 <= xs) and (y1 <= ys) and (xs <= x2) and (ys <= y2):
        return ('cool')
    elif (x1 <= xs) and (y2 <= ys) and (xs <= x2) and (ys <= y1):
        return ('cool')
    elif (x2 <= xs) and (y1 <= ys) and (xs <= x1) and (ys <= y2):
        return ('cool')
    elif (x2 <= xs) and (y2 <= ys) and (xs <= x1) and (ys <= y1):
        return ('cool')
    else:
        return ('uncool')
```

x1,x2,y1,y2 are the are the beginning/ endpoints of the first line segment

x21,x22,y21,y22 are the are the beginning/ endpoints of the second line segment

xs,ys are the coordinates of the intersection

it always gives out 'uncool' shouldn't be right

For testing purposes
i chose

```
x1=4
x2=5
y1=4
y2=6
x21 = 8
x22 = 1
y21 = 1
y22 = 8
```

with these coordinates xs and ys are 4,33 and 4,66

thanks in advance

Comment: I just tried your given input with `xs=4.33` and `ys=4.66`, which I guess is what you meant. It worked fine. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your logic are right here (I get 'cool' too). But if you use `retutn` I suppose you use function. So your mistake is because of incorrect function use (maybe you need to check the scope of variables)

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the way in which you are referencing the global constants. (it's hard to know without your complete function.) Global constants must be declared with the `global` keyword in your [function definition if you wish to reference them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them).

The following function will return the string `cool`.

```
def intersections(xs, ys):
    # global variable declarations
    global x1
    global x2
    global y1
    global y2
    global x21
    global x22
    global y21
    global y22
    str_test = ''
    if (x1 <= xs) and (y1 <= ys) and (xs <= x2) and (ys <= y2):
        str_test = 'cool'
    elif (x1 <= xs) and (y2 <= ys) and (xs <= x2) and (ys <= y1):
        str_test = 'cool'
    elif (x2 <= xs) and (y1 <= ys) and (xs <= x1) and (ys <= y2):
        str_test = 'cool'
    elif (x2 <= xs) and (y2 <= ys) and (xs <= x1) and (ys <= y1):
        str_test = 'cool'
    else:
        str_test = 'uncool'
    return str_test

print intersections(4.33, 4.66)
```